# What's the difference between "test this" and "test this out" (if there is any)?

Tags: meaning, adverbs

"I wanna test this out"

'I wanna test this"

Are there any subtle differences in connotation or are they just the same?

Comment: Avoid the use of "wanna".  This immediately marks your writing.

Comment: The asker doesn't say if they're writing or speaking.

Comment: @JamesK Thanks! I'll keep that in mind. What does "mark your writing" mean though? As in it spills over into my writing when I try to write something formally?

Comment: It means that the writing is "marked",  It appears "odd", or "special" in some way. Writing can be "marked" by being too formal or too informal.  In this case, it marks you as not understanding the appropriate level of formality: so either a non-native speaker, or a juvenile speaker.  It makes it look odd.  I assume you want to write like a grown up.

Comment: @alphabet the they should write using written language. It is acceptable to use "wanna" to represent the sound of spoken language.  But if you are only representing the meaning the written form is "want to".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, "to test" something means to determine if it meets a certain standard, or to evaluate it in some respect.

"To test out" means to try using something to see how it works or how people react to it. It is fairly informal.

For example, you might say:

> I *tested* the car and determined that it gets 20 miles per gallon.

But:

> I *tested out* the car and determined that it is really fun to drive!